# Power utility for starting processes

Tags: optimization, vbscript

I was looking for a way to start elevated (i.e. administrator permissions) and/or invisible processes via batch in Windows. It turns out that this is kind of impossible with batch only, so I googled some vbs stuff and hacked it all together into a neat command line power utility.

The interface is as follows:

```
exec [/action: elevate, open, read, print] [/display: hide, show] exe [arguments]
```

`/action` defaults to `open`. `/display` defaults to `show`. `exe` is the path to an executeable, could be a script, image, whatever as well. `arguments` are applied to the `exe`.

Example: This starts a background node.js deamon with admin rights.

```
exec /action:elevate /display:hide node myDeamon.js
```

Everything works just fine, but I'm pretty sure that it's not perfect yet, as I basically have no idea about VBScript. I'd like to hear your opinions or ideas!

```vb
Set objShell = CreateObject("Shell.Application")

intOffset = 0

' get action
strAction = "open"
If (WScript.Arguments.Named.Exists("action")) Then
  intOffset = intOffset + 1
  Select Case WScript.Arguments.Named.Item("action")
        Case "elevate" strAction = "runas"
        Case "open" strAction = "open"
        Case "read" strAction = "read"
        Case "print" strAction = "print"
        Case Else strAction = "open"
    End Select
End If

' get display mode
intMode = 1
If (WScript.Arguments.Named.Exists("display")) Then
    intOffset = intOffset + 1
    Select Case WScript.Arguments.Named.Item("display")
        Case "0" intMode = 0
        Case "false" intMode = 0
        Case "hide" intMode = 0
        Case "hidden" intMode = 0
        Case Else intMode = 1
    End Select
End If

' get application to execute
strApplication = WScript.Arguments(intOffset)

' get arguments
strArguments = ""
For i = intOffset+1 To WScript.Arguments.Count-1
    strArguments = strArguments & WScript.Arguments(i)
Next

' execute application
If (WScript.Arguments.Count >= 1) Then
    objShell.ShellExecute strApplication, strArguments, "", strAction, intMode
Else
    WScript.Quit
End If
```

[Gist](https://gist.github.com/4281665)

Comment: silvinci, please include the relevant code directly in your question as required by the [faq].

Comment: Done. Just thought it would be too lengthy.

Answer (score 2):

The number one improvement you can make is to include [`Option Explicit`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bw9t3484%28v=vs.84%29.aspx) as the first line of your script and explicitly declare your variables using `Dim`. This will save you a lot of heartache in the future (e.g., if you make a typo in a variable name, it becomes a runtime error, instead of just silently creating a new variable).

Comment: This sounds pretty reasonable. Thanks. Do I have to `Dim` in `For` statements?

Comment: If you have a statement `For i = 1 To 10`, then you must declare `i` with `Dim i`, if that's what you're asking.